# How to know at what level a child is in deeply nested object?

Tags: javascript

I have recursive function which prints every child in a deeply nested object.

```js
const tree = {
            name: "Anand",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Dashrath",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Sitesh",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "Yadnesh",
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Machindra",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Tejas",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "Tanishka",
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ],
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Amol",
                            children: [],
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Amit",
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

        function printTree(t) {
            if (t.children.length === 0) {
                return
            }
            t.children.forEach((child,index) => {
                    console.log(child.name);                
                printTree(child);
            })
        }
        printTree(tree);
```

output : dashrath, sitesh, yadnesh, machindra, tanishka, amol, amit

and I want something like this **1st gen dashrath, 2nd gen sitesh, 3rd gen yadnesh, 1st gen machindra, 2nd gen tejas, 3rd gen tanishka, 2nd gen amol, 3rd gen amit**

Comment: Unrelated: You can remove `if (t.children.length === 0) { return }`. It's okay to call `forEach` on an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the `printTree` function accept a `depth` parameter and increment it appropriately with each recursive call, something like this:

```
function printTree(t, depth = 0) {
    if (t.children.length === 0) {
        return
    }
    t.children.forEach((child,index) => {
        // you'd need to do some extra formatting here if you
        // want ordinals like "1st", "2nd", etc.
        console.log(`gen ${depth + 1}: ${child.name}`);                
        printTree(child, depth + 1);
    })
}
printTree(tree);
```

Comment: Give it a default `gen=0` so you don't need to pass it in the initial call.

Comment: @Barmar Good idea.

Comment: man this was the first ever question I asked on stackoverflow I didn't know that I will get my answer that fast. I really appreciate that man. Thank you!

Comment: can someone explain me why depth is getting formatted to zero when its iterating over next child of main parent.

Comment: @SiddheshYadav Can you explain more what you mean by "getting formatted to zero"?